# ${\Lambda}_k(V)$ is spanned by a basis $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let ${\Lambda}_k(V)$ be the set of all the multilinear-alternating functions from $\prod_{i = 1}^k V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We are going to suppose that $k \leq n = \dim V$ and $\{v_1 , \ldots , v_n\}$ and $\{v_1^* , \ldots , v_n^*\}$ are basis for $V$ and $V^*$ respectively. Fix $f \in {\Lambda}_k(V)$ and I want to show that
$$
f = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n} {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*\right)\mbox{,}
$$
being ${\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} = f(v_{i_1} , \ldots , v_{i_k})$, which implies that ${\Lambda}_k(V)$ is spanned by
$$
\mathcal{B} = {\left\{\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}\right\}}_{1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n}\mbox{.}
$$

In http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/michael.murray/dg_hons/node25.html can be found that it is suggested to develop the right member of last equation and it's my attemp about. Fixed $u_j \in V$, $k = 1 , \ldots , k$, I am trying to prove that
$$
\sum_{1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n} {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*\right)(u_1 , \ldots , u_k) = f(u_1 , \ldots , u_k)\mbox{.}
$$
Well, at first we need to express $u_k$ through the vectors $v_i$, $i = 1 , \ldots , n$. We are going to suppose that
$$
u_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i^j v_i \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad j = 1 , \ldots , k\mbox{.}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{{i_1 , \ldots , i_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \atop {i_1 < \ldots < i_k}} f(v_{i_1} , \ldots , v_{i_k}) \left(\bigwedge_{l = 1}^k v_{i_l}^*\right)(u_1 , \ldots , u_k) =
$$
$$
= \sum_{{i_1 , \ldots , i_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \atop {i_1 < \ldots < i_k}} f(v_{i_1} , \ldots , v_{i_k}) \left(\sum_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \left(\prod_{l = 1}^k {\lambda}_{j_l}^l\right) \left(\bigwedge_{l = 1}^k v_{i_l}^*\right)(u_1 , \ldots , u_k)\right) =
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{k !} \sum_{{i_1 , \ldots , i_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \atop {i_1 < \ldots < i_k}} f(v_{i_1} , \ldots , v_{i_k}) \left(\sum_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \left(\prod_{l = 1}^k {\lambda}_{j_l}^l\right) \left(\sum_{\sigma \in G_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k}} sgn(\sigma) \left(\prod_{l = 1}^k {\delta}_{i_l , \sigma(j_l)}\right)\right)\right) =
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{k !} \sum_{{i_1 , \ldots , i_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}} \atop {i_1 < \ldots < i_k}} f(v_{i_1} , \ldots , v_{i_k}) \left(\sum_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \atop \sigma \in S_k} sgn(\sigma)\left(\prod_{l = 1}^k {\lambda}_{j_l}^l {\delta}_{i_l , j_{\sigma(l)}}\right)\right)\mbox{,}
$$
where $G_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k} \cong S_k$, being $\psi : S_k \to G_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k}$, given by $\psi : l \mapsto j_l$ an isomorphism ($G_{j_1 , \ldots , j_k}$ is essentially $S_k$). I do not know how I can continue since here. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use `1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n` for the result $1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n$, which makes just one line and a less tiny output.

Comment: Thank you by your suggestion. I have just modified the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the step $$
\sum_{1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n} {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*\right)(u_1 , \ldots , u_k) = \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \ldots < i_k\leq n} {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*(u_j)\right)$$
is wrong.

If this were true, for instance you would have $$e_1^*\wedge e_2^*(e_2,e_1)=e_1^*(e_2)e_2^*(e_1)=0$$
instead of the expected $$e_1^*\wedge e_2^*(e_2,e_1)=-e_1^*\wedge e_2^*(e_1,e_2)=-1.$$

So what you need to do is split the $u_i$ before feeding them to the $v_{i_j}^*$.

---

The correct continuation from there is
$$
\sum {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*\right)(u_1 , \ldots , u_k) =\sum {\lambda}_{i_1 , \ldots , i_k} \left(\bigwedge_{j = 1}^k v_{i_j}^*\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i^1 v_i , \ldots , \sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i^n v_i\right) 
$$
Then use multilinearity and consider all ways to select one $v_i$ at a time so as to have exactly the list $\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_n}\}$ in the end (with a possible minus sign depending on the parity of the permutation).

Note, however, that you don't have to **actually** do this. Only observe that it can be done, and that it can be done in the exact same manner for $f$ since it is multilinear and alternate as well, giving the same coefficients that depend on the matrix $[\lambda_i^j]$.

Comment: How can I split the $u_i$?

Comment: @joseabp91 You did it already, you defined the coordinates $\lambda_i^j$.

Comment: So, how can I prove the equality? I do not understand.

Comment: @joseabp91 I edited.

Comment: I have just developed the right member of your equation using multinilearity but I have obtained the same than before.

Comment: Could you post what you get when $ n=2 $ without summation symbol?

Comment: Which $k$ do I choose?

Comment: @joseabp91 $ k=2 $ as well.

Comment: I get that this was a mistake. Thank you Arnaut mortier. I am going to transform the answer within a few hours and wait a new answer for that.

Comment: I have just modified.